# Listbox Scroll To End In Windows phone 7

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, xaml, expression-blend

I have listbox in my wp7 application. When An Item is Added into It I Want My Scroll Goes To An End.

I Tried This Thing

```
var Selecteditem = listmy.Items[listmy.Items.Count - 1];
listmy.ScrollIntoView(Selecteditem);
listmy.UpdateLayout();
```

But Nothing Happened. Is There any other way to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

probably UI is not updated yet just after new item was added. Put all this code into a `Dispatcher` block

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
{
    var Selecteditem = listmy.Items[listmy.Items.Count - 1];
    listmy.ScrollIntoView(Selecteditem);
    listmy.UpdateLayout(); 
});
```